# getting image width and height from javascript when using asp.net FileUpload

Tags: javascript, asp.net

that's my code :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#<%=fileUpload.ClientID%>").change(function () {
    alert(// width + height ); 
    });
    });
   </script>

<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" class="upload"   />
```

Can i get the width and height of uploaded image from client side ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you get the attributes of the image before the image is uploaded ? How could you be sure its even an image ? The client or server does not know anything about the file prior to upload. As far as I know, you can only get the name and size of the file.

Comment: that's just a peace of my code i can detect the type of the uploaded image but how can i check for it's width and height ?

Comment: Like I said, before the image is uploaded, you can't get anything else than file size and name.

By "detecting" do you mean using a filter for the file selection dialog ? That is far from a bulletproof detection method.

Comment: check this link http://jsfiddle.net/4N6D9/1/ it's not working for me maybe because i'm using an asp control but i want a different solution

Comment: For the third time: **the file needs to be uploaded for this to work**

Comment: i get it hehe but have you checked the link ? it can give you the width and height of the image before you actually uploading it to the server i know that you can't upload files using javascript and you should use a server side language and i know that i can get the name and the size of the file uploaded but my only question is can i get the height and the width of the image

Comment: No. No. No. No. No. No. No. A completely different thing is if you load an existing image from the web, but getting anything else than file name and size of an image that resides in a user's drive, no. In your code, you just create an empty image and try to load if from a URL.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16241/discussion-between-sora-and-endy)